# How to save XML file and send it to another page.

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I am creating XML file from database. 
on first page I save result from database to XML and try to `echo $dom->saveXML();` to see if it was created (yes, it was). Than I have added

```
$redirect = 'second_page.php'; header('Location: ' . $redirect);
```

To redirect on my second page. Where the XML file should be loaded on map with ( but it dont).

```
downloadUrl("first_page.php", function(data)
```

Do I need to save somehow else the XML file? Because it looks like result was lost on the road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [saveXML](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php) (which you are using) returns a string.

But I think that you want to save the xml to a file. You can do that with the  [save](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.save.php) function.

On your next page, you can load your file using the [load](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.load.php) function.